# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataset_generation'

Tags: python, pip

Facing issue with dataset_generation.

Below is the module, I am trying to call

`from dataset_generation.dataset_utils import download_pdf_file`

And getting the error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-9e3a66ab2ddf> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 from unpywall import Unpywall, UnpywallCache
      5 from unpywall.utils import UnpywallCredentials
----> 6 from dataset_generation.dataset_utils import download_pdf_file

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataset_generation'
```

Comment: What module is that supposed to be? There is no package by that name on pypi. You ahve tagged `pip`, so I am assuming you ran some pip command to install it? can you add that to your question using the [edit] function

Answer (score 0):

The error might be in the way you import your modules.
I will show an example of how you can handle your imports.

In this example `/root_dir/main.py` imports dependencies from `/root_dir/module1_dir/module1.py` who in turn imports `root_dir/module2_dir/module2.py`.
[image]

This is how their imports should be done:

### main.py

```
import module1_dir.module1
```

### module1.py

```
import module2_dir.module2
```

This also applies in this scenario:

[image]

You might be tempted to think that in this scenario you could get away with this import in `module1.py`:

```
import module2
```

But since your main thread's current working directory is in `root_dir` you need to specify the full path even in the `sub_dir` modules.